# How does one publish a map to the web?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

Just starting out with ArcGIS server at work, I've had no prior experience but I been given the responsibility to display our map on the web.

I have a ArcGIS server running on a server and I am using ArcMap 10 on my desktop.  I created a Folder in the server where I saved the map document.  I can add a new service using this document and I'm given a url when I do so.  But when I go to that URL I get this error:

`Server Error in '/ArcGIS/Services' Application.
Runtime Error`

And, when going to the same url from the server I get:
`Server Error in '/ArcGIS/Services' Application.
No Content`

Comment: I can't answer your question, but you may find more answers over on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to open servername/ArcGIS/services via browser? This url is for SOAP requests, e.g. you can add '?wsdl' to it ang get SOAP service description. To use it with browser you'll need  ArcGIS Server REST API, i.e. use 'servername/ArcGIS/**rest**/services' URL.